# How do I do a sub query in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: jobs and positive (a list of words associated with a job id).

I'm trying to produce an object like:

```
{
title: "foo",
positive: [...,...,...],
}
```

Is it possible with sql?

```
SELECT j.* FROM jobs as j WHERE positive = (
          SELECT word FROM positive as p WHERE p.search_id = j.id
        )
       ORDER BY j.created_at
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expcet result?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query:

```sql
select j.title, group_concat(p.name) as 'positive'
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN  positive p ON p.jid = j.id
GROUP BY j.title;
```

You can use a string split when you build your domain object

[image: tables an query result]